# Multiple tables in the where clause that start with the same string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using sql-server 2014 and am trying to select ID values from a table where the ID values do not exist in hundreds of other tables which all start with the same string (e.g. MyTable1, MyTable2, MyTable3, etc.)

My current query is something like this...

```
select ID from want w
where not exists (select 'x' from MyTable1 m1 where m1.ID = w.id)
and not exists (select 'x' from MyTable2 m2 where m2.ID = w.id)
```

I'm looking for something like

```
select ID from want w
where not exists (select 'x' from 'MyTable%' m where m.ID = w.id)
```

Or

```
select ID from want w
where ID not in 
(select ID from 'MyTable%')
```

Thank you!

Comment: SQL Server 2014 has no support anymore, is it not time to upgrade ?

Comment: You will need dynamic sql for this, look this up in google you will find lots of examples

Comment: Yes, you will need dynamic SQL for this and use this query: `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` for selecting all needing tables

Answer (score 0):

You do mention that there are hundreds of other tables, is the number of tables increasing? Using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES as already mentioned in the comments in your question along with dynamic SQL would be a start but also look up cursors for looping through the table names with the result-set returned from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES. The code fragment below will loop through the table listing from information_schema on the default database. You'll have to add your own code depending on what you want to do where the 'if' statement is. The variable @Table_Name has the name of the table, so you would need to include this in a dynamic SQL string and execute this to get your unused ids.

```
declare @table_name varchar(256);

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM [Datasets].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
;

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @TABLE_NAME  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    if(@Table_Name like 'Airline%')
        print('Have table name to work with: ' + @Table_Name);
    else
        print('Ignoring table: ' + @Table_name);

      FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @TABLE_NAME 
END 

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```